# is this proper use of an if statement in php

Tags: php, html

I would like for a statement with a letter grade to be displayed when a user inputs a number within the set range. Is my logic and syntax correct?

```
<form action = student.php method="get">
   Accounting: 
   <input type=text name=accounting_grade><br><br>
   History:
   <input type=text name=history_grade><br><br>

   <input type=submit value="Click">

</form>
```

and the php code

```
<?php

    $acct_grd = $_GET['accounting_grade'];
    $hist_grd = $_GET['history_grade'];

    if($acct_grd = > 90 && < 101 ){
        echo "You earned an A in this course";
    elseif ($acct_grd = > 80 && < 91 )
        echo "You earned a B in this course";
    elseif ($acct_grd = > 70 && < 81 )
        echo "You earned a C in this course";
    elseif($acct_grd = > 60 && < 71 )
        echo "You earned an D in this course";
    elseif($acct_grd = < 60)
        echo "You earned an F in this course";

    }

?>
```

Comment: consider adding what your current results are when running/testing your code

Comment: Your `= >` needs to be `>=`

Comment: Also you need another comparison or you draw an error `if($acct_grd >= 90 && $acct_grd < 101 )`

Comment: You don't actually need to check a range in each test. Just the lower limit test is needed. It will stop at the first correct grade. i.e.  `if ($acct_grd >= 90 { grade A } elseif ($acct_grd >= 80) { grade B }` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code should be more like this. Values that are non-numeric should be in quotes.

```
<form action="student.php" method="get">
Accounting: 
<input type="text" name="accounting_grade"><br><br>
History:
<input type="text" name="history_grade"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit grades">
</form>
```

You can get away with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$acct_grd = $_GET['accounting_grade'];

echo "for accounting...";
if($acct_grd >= 90 && $acct_grd < 101 ){
    echo "You earned an A in this course";
}elseif($acct_grd >= 80 && $acct_grd < 90 ){
    echo "You earned a B in this course";
}elseif($acct_grd >= 70 && $acct_grd < 80 ){
    echo "You earned a C in this course";
}elseif($acct_grd >= 60 && $acct_grd < 70 ){
    echo "You earned an D in this course";
}else{
echo "You earned an F in this course";
}

$acct_grd = $_GET['history_grade'];

echo " and for history...";
if($acct_grd >= 90 && $acct_grd < 101 ){
    echo "You earned an A in this course";
}elseif($acct_grd >= 80 && $acct_grd < 90 ){
    echo "You earned a B in this course";
}elseif($acct_grd >= 70 && $acct_grd < 80 ){
    echo "You earned a C in this course";
}elseif($acct_grd >= 60 && $acct_grd < 70 ){
    echo "You earned an D in this course";
}else{
echo "You earned an F in this course";
}
?>
```

However, starting at `$acct_grd = $_GET['history_grade'];`, you may want to replace `$acct_grd` with `$acct_hist` so you know what variable represents what subject.

Change the text in the echo statements to suit your website needs.